# tabs dinamicamente jquery

Tags: bootstrap-3

boas é o seguinte estou a usar o datatables e quando clico uma valor abre um modal. so que queria colocar isto abrir numa nova tab e não sei como fazer.

teria por exemplo tab principal clientes onde tenho um form para pesquisar e mostrar o datatables e apos clicar em abrir mais de detalhes abria uma nova tab.

exemplo 
http://www.igest.pt/igest/

Modal

```
<div class="modal fade bs-detalhes-modal-lg" id="details" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" id="conteudoModal">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-mini" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

o script seguinte vai adicionar uma nova tab só que não me redirecciona para ela
sendo que o load (id) é um onclick que recebe um valor por parametero

```
    function load(id) {
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "./modals/info.php",
        data: {id: id},
        success: function (data) {
            $('.nav-tabs').append('<li class="nav"> <a href="#detalhes" data-toggle="tab" id="' + id + '" onclick="update(this.id)">'+'Cod' + id + '  <button class="close closeTab" type="button" >×</button></a></li>');
            $('.tab-content').append('<div class="tab-pane active" id="' + id + '"></div>');
            $("#conteudoModal").html(data);
            document.getElementById("show").style.display = "";

        }

    });

    $('#detalhes').tab('active');

    }
```

Comment: Poste o codigo aqui para facilitar a analise da galera.

Comment: nao tenho codigo ainda feito

Comment: Onde está o exemplo no site que você deu?

Comment: na area de listagem de clientes, tem de fazer teste gratis, depois ai é que ve ao clicar na lupa abre uma nova tab